# texts on the highlighted line is hidden when ^n in vim on ssh

Tags: vim, ssh

[image]

as you can see in the included picture, unlike in the ubuntu terminal above,
texts on highlighted line is hidden by the black bar on ssh. I'm using windows 10 remote terminal app. any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be migrated to vi.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your SSH session has fewer colors available (probably just 16 or even 8; you can check with `:set t_Co?` inside Vim), and therefore the low contrast *popup menu selection* highlighting (which I would want to fix even on Ubuntu terminal; see below) becomes a *no contrast selection* (black on black). To fix this:

- Check whether your Windows 10 remote terminal app actually supports more colors (I think it should allow at least 256 different colors), and tweak the `TERM` environment variable before starting Vim (e.g. by changing `xterm` to `xterm-256color`).
- Switch to a different `:colorscheme`; Vim ships with several, and many more can be found at [vim.org](https://www.vim.org/) or on the Internet.
- Keep the colorscheme (if you like it in general), but tweak this particular highlight group ([`:help hl-PmenuSel`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/syntax.txt.html#hl-PmenuSel)). Put the corresponding `:highlight PmenuSel ...` command after the *:colorscheme* command in your `~/.vimrc`.

Comment: :highlight Pmenu ctermbg=blue guibg=blue
:highlight PmenuSel ctermbg=yellow guibg=yellow
:highlight PmenuSbar ctermbg=green guibg=green
:highlight PmenuThumb ctermbg=snow guibg=snow with this commands I fixed the issue. thank you so much.